# How to define or set my local yaml values mentioned above in kubernetes value.yaml with underscore like backbase_communication_channels

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, deployment, gitlab-ci-runner

I have deployed the java service in kubernetes environment, I have faced with the issue  that cannot convert the application.yml in the service to value.yaml in kubernetes.

1.---application.yml

```
backbase:
  communication:
    channels:
      email:
        "0": email-low-priority
        "1-6": email-high-priority
        "7": email-highest-priority
      sms:
        "0": sms-low-priority
        "1-6": sms-high-priority
        "7": sms-highest-priority
```

2--- java code in spring boot

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(
prefix = "backbase.communication"
)
public class MessageChannelProperties {
private Map<String, Map<Range<Integer>, String>> channels;

public MessageChannelProperties() {
}

@Generated
public Map<String, Map<Range<Integer>, String>> getChannels() {
 return this.channels;
}

@Generated
public void setChannels(final Map<String, Map<Range<Integer>, String>> channels) {
 this.channels = channels;
}
}
```

3-- values.yml? how can I covert to values.yml in kubernetes

Thank you

-Need the service can understand the config from kubernetes

Comment: A `src/main/resources/application.yml` file is usually compiled into your jar file; you wouldn't need to repeat it at deployment time.  A Helm `values.yaml` file is specific to the chart and how it uses the values.  Can you say a little more about what your Helm chart does (assuming you are in fact using Helm), and what you need to configure at deployment time?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.